# How to display only min, median and max in box plot chart?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having issues formating my x-axis in my boxplotchart in nvd3. Here is what I am getting:

[image]

And here is what I would like to get (this is done by default on the line chart in nvd3):

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

This is how I build my boxplotchart:

```
    var chart = nv.models.boxPlotChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d.label })
                .y(function(d) { return d.values.Q3 })
                .color(["#B6CCEA"])
                .margin({"right":50});
            chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel(CONSTANTS.CHARTS.BUILDS_BOXPLOT.X_AXIS)
                .showMaxMin(true)
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                    return moment(d).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
                });
```

Workaround:

What I've done so far to get rid of those labels: I've added the followings css:

```
div#builds-boxplot > svg > g.nvd3 > g > g.nv-x > g.nv-axis > g > g.tick {
  display: none;
}

div#tests-boxplot > svg > g.nvd3 > g > g.nv-x > g.nv-axis > g > g.tick {
  display: none;
}

div#builds-line > svg > g.nvd3 > g > g.nv-x > g.nv-axis > g > g.tick {
  display: none;
}

div#tests-line > svg > g.nvd3 > g > g.nv-x > g.nv-axis > g > g.tick {
  display: none;
}
```

However, I am pretty sure this is not the right solution.

Comment: You need to share some of your code and your data to get help.

Comment: @altocumulus I have added code that I use to build my boxplot